# Regarding Integration of Braintree payment Gateway and Java

Tags: java, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am new to payment gateway integration.I need to integrate `Braintree Payment Gateway` with JSF Application. Can someone show my a basic example of the java class and sample payment Page. I saw some client Token how to generate it. I wrote a sample class and page like below,But i coudnt make as i dont get the idea.

**page**

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
    <div id="payment-form"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay $15">
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
    // We generated a client token for you so you can test out this code
    // immediately. In a production-ready integration, you will need to
    // generate a client token on your server (see section below).
    var clientToken = "sZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJtZXJjaGFudElkIjoiMzQ4cGs5Y2dmM2JneXcyYiIsInZlbm1vIjoib2ZmIn0=";

    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container : "payment-form"
    });

</script>
```

**Class**

```
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;

import com.braintreegateway.BraintreeGateway;
import com.braintreegateway.Environment;

public class BrainTreeController {
    private static BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway(
              Environment.SANDBOX,
              "your_merchant_id",
              "your_public_key",
              "your_private_key"
            );
        post(new Route("/client_token") {
          @Override
          public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
            return gateway.clientToken().generate();
          }
        });
}
```

I get a error in post

```
Syntax error on token "post", @ expected before this token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the below sample from the [Braintree Java SDK Implementation](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_java). Integrate this in your project according to requirements:

```
public class BrainTreeImplementation {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BrainTreeImplementation.class.getName());

// Below are the Braintree sandbox credentials
private static BraintreeGateway gateway = null;
private static String publicKey = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY";
private static String privateKey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY";
private static String merchantId= "YOUR_MERCHANT_ID";   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialize Braintree Connection
    gateway = connectBraintreeGateway();
    braintreeProcessing();
}

public static void braintreeProcessing() {

    System.out.println(" ----- BrainTree Implementation Starts --- ");

    // Generate client Token
    String clientToken = generateClientToken();
    System.out.println(" Client Token : " +clientToken);

    // Receive payment method nonce
    String nonceFromTheClient = receivePaymentMethodNonce();

    // Do payment transactions
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("5.10");
    doPaymentTransaction(nonceFromTheClient, amount);
}

// Connect to Braintree Gateway.
public static BraintreeGateway connectBraintreeGateway() {
    BraintreeGateway braintreeGateway = new BraintreeGateway(
            Environment.SANDBOX, merchantId, publicKey, privateKey);
    return braintreeGateway;
}

// Make an endpoint which return client token.
public static String generateClientToken() {
    // client token will be generated at server side and return to client
    String clientToken = gateway.clientToken().generate();
    return clientToken;
}

// Make an endpoint which receive payment method nonce from client and do payment.
public static String receivePaymentMethodNonce() {
     String nonceFromTheClient =  "fake-valid-mastercard-nonce";
     return nonceFromTheClient;
}

// Make payment 
public void String doPaymentTransaction(String paymentMethodNonce, BigDecimal amount) {

    TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest();
    request.amount(amount);
    request.paymentMethodNonce(paymentMethodNonce);

    CustomerRequest customerRequest = request.customer();
    customerRequest.email("cpatel@gmail.com");
    customerRequest.firstName("Chirag");
    customerRequest.lastName("Patel");

    TransactionOptionsRequest options = request.options();
    options.submitForSettlement(true);

    // Done the transaction request
    options.done();

    // Create transaction ...
    Result<Transaction> result = gateway.transaction().sale(request);
    boolean isSuccess = result.isSuccess();

    if (isSuccess) {
        Transaction transaction = result.getTarget();
        displayTransactionInfo(transaction);
    } else {
        ValidationErrors errors = result.getErrors();
        validationError(errors);
    }
}

private static void displayTransactionInfo(Transaction transaction) {
    System.out.println(" ------ Transaction Info ------ ");
    System.out.println(" Transaction Id  : " +transaction.getId());
    System.out.println(" Processor Response Text : " +transaction.getProcessorResponseText());
}

private static void validationError(ValidationErrors errors) {
    List<ValidationError> error = errors.getAllDeepValidationErrors();
    for (ValidationError er : error) {
        System.out.println(" error code : " + er.getCode());
        System.out.println(" error message  : " + er.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how do i make a subscription @ckpatel i Tried PaymentMethod paymentmethod = generatePaymentMethod("31558878");
    SubscriptionRequest subscribtionrequest = new SubscriptionRequest()   ;
      .paymentMethodToken(paymentmethod.getToken())
      .id("Subsc31558878").planId(plan.getId())
      .paymentMethodNonce(receivePaymentMethodNonce())
      .neverExpires(false).billingDayOfMonth(30)
      .firstBillingDate(date).price(plan.getPrice()).addOns()
      .done();Result<Subscription> subscresult = gateway.subscription()
      .create(subscribtionrequest);